# Permutations - Organized Counting

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For this problem, I have completed parts a), c), and d) using the permutation function. I was hoping someone could let me know if my approaches to answer them are correct? Also I've tried working on b) but I still have no idea how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated.

**The question:**

> You are setting up a system of programming codes for a universal TV remote. Each code will have five digits and cannot include a $0$ or repeat digits. How many codes:
> a) do not have a $7$?
> b) have $3$ as the third digit and $5$ as the fifth digit?
> c) begin with an even number?
> d) begin and end with an even number?

**My approches:**

a) How many codes do not have a $7$?

I used the permutation function here: $_8P_5 = 6720$

b) How many codes have 3 as the third digit and 5 as the fifth digit?

I don't know how to answer this part.

c) How many codes begin with an even number?

$\text{Total number of codes} =\ _9P_5 = 15120$ 
$\text{Number of codes that begin with an even number} = \frac{4}{9}\times 15120 = 6720$

d) How many codes begin and end with an even number?

$\text{Number of codes that begin with an even number} = 6720$ 
$\text{Number of codes that end and begin with even numbers} = \frac{3}{8}\times 6720 = 2520$

Comment: For _b)_ you have two digits defined already, so you choose remaining three from six – and you can use the permutation function again to count possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Your approaches are correct in parts $(a), (c)$, and $(d)$.

This is what I'd do for the part $(b)$: You have nine numbers, but can use only five without repitition. If you put two numbers (3 and 5) for specific places, you have only seven numbers to fill three remaining spaces of the code. Thus the total combinations are:
$$_7P_3 = \frac{7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1} = 210$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you have completed parts (a), (c) and (d). The approaches are correct! For the remaining part, simply think about what digits the remaining positions can take in `_ _ 3 _ 5` out of `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` (so similar to your part (a)). (The answer is 210 but try to find the permutation function for it as well). Hope it helps.